# struts2 Could not find token name in params

Tags: struts2

this is the configuration of struts:

```
<interceptors>
        <interceptor-stack name="packStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="token" />
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>

    <default-interceptor-ref name="packStack" />
```

and i got this warning and token interceptor is not blocking the duplicate submission of requests.

```
WARNING: Could not find token name in params.
```

i have searched the web and so many forums. how to solve this?? i have tried changing the order of the interceptors and at last i have arranged like above.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`<s:token>` tag](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/token.html), otherwise there won't be a token parameter, sort of like the message says.

Comment: i have already placed this tag in form : 
 <s:token name="dupFilter" /> but no use

Comment: @sanjeev Did you try it without a "name" attribute? Also, what version of S2? I can't dupe your problem.

Comment: yes i tried it with out the name. but the result is same. i want to apply token interceptor for all the actions in the package. is the xml configuration shown above is correct?? i am using struts2

Comment: @sanjeev And the version of S2? If I don't know that, I can't test it locally.

Comment: @sanjeev I'd put a minimally failing project on github and follow up here; it works fine for me, so I'll need more details.